# Accessing alternate data streams in files

Tags: c#, .net, windows, file-io, ntfs

On an NTFS file system, it is possible to have alternate data streams within a single file. Is it possible to access this information in a **fully managed** way?

**EDIT:** additionally, I want to read from the alternate stream in an existing file. How is this achieved (using PInvoke if not possible using managed code only)?

<sub>[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/604960/116923) is similar, but is from early 2009 and the .Net answer uses PInvoke to write to a file, not read from it. Has support for this been added since then (to .Net 4.0?) that can do it without using PInvoke?</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is still no access via a managed .Net Framework API.

**Update**

Here's a library\source for an ADS access wrapper:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ntfsstreams.aspx