# Unblock File from within .net 4 c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, pinvoke, alternate-data-stream

Is there a possibility to unblock a file that is downloaded from the internet from within a c# program. 
Surfing the internet I have learned, that the information is written in an alternative stream of a (NTFS) file that contains the current zone information (value 3 is from the internet and is interpreted as blocked).

Is there a managed possiblity to either clear or change the zone information (unblock) of a file or is there a managed copy function that copies the files without the zone information?
If not, how can I do with PInvoke but without including a foreign assembly (I'm not allowed to do this in a current project).

Comment: @Sven: Thanks: I thought that I have exactly this written in my question. Is my english so bad? But thanks anyway... :)

Comment: No, apparently my reading skills are, though. :) In my defense, it's after midnight here. Fwiw, you'll have to use PInvoke, as the .Net System.IO classes don't support alternate data streams.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/604960/ntfs-alternate-data-streams-net

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's stored in the `:Zone.Identifier` stream (`more < c:\theapp.exe:Zone.Identifier`) you need to use the native IO routines to manipulate them, here is a [managed wrapper](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/ntfsstreams.aspx).

Comment: While this may work for now, it is an implementation detail.  The [Persistent Zone Identifier object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537029(v=vs.85).aspx), as mentioned by @citizenmatt, is the bit responsible for creating these.  As such, MS may at any time, via Windows update or OS version, change how/where that data is stored.

Answer (score 42):

Based on your input I have done the following code:

```
public class FileUnblocker {
    [DllImport("kernel32", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool DeleteFile(string name);

    public bool Unblock(string fileName) {
        return DeleteFile(fileName + ":Zone.Identifier");
    }
}
```

Thanks to Stuart Dunkeld, Alex K(+1) and Sven to show me the direction.

**UPDATE**
I have posted the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375599/looks-this-pinvoke-correct-and-reliable) for a feedback if it would work reliable in production environment. If someone want to use it, check out there.

Comment: Updates like this should be posted as an edit to your question.

Answer (score 6):

The official way to manage this identifier is with the PersistentZoneIdentifier COM object: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537029(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

I'm using .net 7, I've found these does the same thing.

Unblock:

```
void UnblockFile(string filePath)
{
    File.Delete(filePath + ":Zone.Identifier");
}
```

Block:

```
void BlockFile(string filePath)
{
    File.WriteAllText(filePath + ":Zone.Identifier", "[ZoneTransfer]\r\nZoneId=3");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is to unblock files use a powershell command:

```
dir -r | unblock-files
```

change directory to the folder containing the files and run that command.  The parameter -r is to list files in all sub-folders.