# Test for File Blocked, Un-block it

Tags: vb.net, file

I have a VB.NET executable that I distribute via a ZIP file (along with other supporting files). When the ZIP is downloaded my instructions call for the file properties to be checked and un-blocked if needed. This really only applies to the executable in it, it is just easier to have the user un-block the ZIP file.

A large part of the time this instruction is not followed and I have to work with them to get it taken care of. There is another executable in the ZIP that copies files to where they belong and does some other work.

Can this application check if the main executable is blocked? If so, can it unblock it programmatically?

[image]

Comment: What do you exactly mean with blocked?

Comment: I just added an image showing the Unblock I referenced

Comment: What OS are your clients using? I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375599/is-this-pinvoke-code-correct-and-reliable) question with answer + code example. It seems that you have to use native P/Invoke code.

Comment: Users will be using Windows 7 Pro 64-bit or newer

Comment: I will look at the code from your link, it looks interesting. Thanks.