# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\-i

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, web-services

I am trying to install a web service which is basically a file watcher service. But when I try to run this command `Installutil –i "C:\\xxx\zzzz\ServiceTest.exe"`

I get this error `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\-i`

I used to run this command before and I never got this error, I don't know what is different this time.

Answer (score 7):

I get the same error if I download the windows10manager.exe (exe service sample) from the Internet. After I download the file, I go to file properties and I click in unblock button. After this operation, the service install successfuly. To automate this process, follow this thread: [Unblock File from within .net 4 c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374673/unblock-file-from-within-net-4-c-sharp)

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try running

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe -i "C:\xxx\zzzz\ServiceTest.exe"

The response you received doesn't make sense unless "installutil" has been redefined.

Answer (score 1):

Check the spelling of the service path specially the (") quote character write it and don't copy paste.

This works with me.

Comment: That could have been a helpfull comment, if you told us where do you mean to check...

Answer (score 0):

Change the compiler settings in Visual Studio from **X86** to **Any CPU** or use the 64 bit InstalUtil inside "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319"

Comment: have you changed the compiler settings, recompiled the project and then tried to install it? try rebuilding the web service installer too

Comment: Maybe some of your refereneced DLLs are still 32bit? You can check it with free tool depends.exe from Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some of your refereneced DLLs are still 32bit? You can check it with free tool depends.exe from Microsoft

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this error occur because the are some **blank space** in my project path **e.g.:** C:\user\Visual Studio 2019....

When I rename my path by deleting space, it worked fine

Answer (score -1):

I had same problem, because the service name was only "Service.exe", so i change to C:\MyServices\NewService\Service.exe"

**Wrong**: 
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil /u Service.exe

**Correct**: C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\installutil /u "C:\MyServices\NewService\Service.exe"

works for me!

Comment: Can you explain further **what** you did?

Comment: Did you actually meant to show *uninstalling* syntax?