# Use batch command with c#, without cmd.exe in Process object

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to pass a variable to a file with alternative data stream (ADS) in c#.

Batch example:

**Put a flag:**

echo true > c:\temp\a.7z:flag

**Read the flag:**

more < c:\temp\a.7z:flag

If I pass the batch command as an argument  to cmd.exe (with Process object), I get the start message of cmd.exe:

```
Process myProcess = new Process();

myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = args;
myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = exe;
```

**Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Alle Rechte vorbehalten.
C:\Users...\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\bin\Debug>**

Is there any possibilty to use the batch command without using cmd.exe?

Comment: Show your code (i.e. what you're passing to StartInfo.FileName and StartInfo.Arguments.  I suspect you're just passing the batch name to StartInfo.Arguments; you should be passing "/c myfile.bat".

Comment: You can deal with the [ADS directly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10477059/working-c-sharp-example-writing-reading-ntfs-alternate-data-stream-under-win7) instead of through CMD

Comment: Martheen proposal is better. However, if you still want cmd.exe, you need add /c to arguments. Or you can set UseShellExecute to true and use bat file as FileName