# How do I hide information in a file?

Tags: c#, file

Is it possible to hide information somewhere in a file? For example, I need to save a GUID with each file to make it unique.

Comment: Why does the info need to be hidden? Is it sensitive information? Please provide more details about your scenario.

Comment: What kind of file? Any file? Specific type of file? Is it a file from your application? Another application? Which one?

Comment: You could note the binary hash of the file, which would be unique for each unique file.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't tried them my self but you can try using [NTFS Alternate Data Streams - .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604960/ntfs-alternate-data-streams-net)

Hope this helps

Comment: I was about to suggest that. I've done that, and it seems like a possible solution. Bear in mind ADS only work on NTFS - if a file is copied to a FAT32 drive (say disk on key) or sent over the network, the alternate streams will be stripped.

Comment: Also you can execute command line process for adding hidden data: `ECHO "Hidden text" > ordinary_file.txt:hidden.txt`

Comment: ...and to view hidden ADS with notepad: `NOTEPAD ordinary_file.txt:hidden.txt`

Answer (score 0):

If you are wanting to write encrypted data to a text file then this MSDN article explains what to do step by step: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307010