# Obtaining file extended properties in .Net Core

Tags: c#, file, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to read extended properties like `Product Version`, `Author`, etc. from a file using `.Net Core`.

There were classes like `FileVersionInfo` that used to provide version information, Shell object to read more about file, etc.

Now, I don't find such classes any more. How do I read such info using `.Net Core`?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IO.FileSystem/

Comment: It contains FileInfo class which gives basic info, not extended properties

Comment: What "extended property" do you want to read exactly?

Comment: Metadata properties - when  you right-click file in Windows, Properties, Details. Add my own Properties and Values there.

Comment: Adding custom properties to a file seems complicated, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20632612/2698119

Comment: @JohanFoley - this is a composite view of many things, and you cannot add your own in every situation

Answer (score 15):

`FileVersionInfo` can be easily found on [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo/), it's been located in 
[`System.Diagnostics`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.aspx) namespace from the beginning, so you need just to install the package:

```
Install-Package System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo
```

and use this class as usual, [getting the file info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.filesystems.ifileinfo.physicalpath.aspx) from some [`IFileProvider`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers#file-provider-implementations), for example, `PhysicalFileProvider`:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

var provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(applicationRoot);
// the applicationRoot contents
var contents = provider.GetDirectoryContents("");
// a file under applicationRoot
var fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo("wwwroot/js/site.js");
// version information
var myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(fileInfo.PhysicalPath);
//  myFileVersionInfo.ProductVersion is available here
```

For `Author` information you should use [`FileSecurity`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.security.accesscontrol.filesecurity) class, which is located in [`System.Security.AccessControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.security.accesscontrol) namespace, with type [`System.Security.Principal.NTAccount`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.ntaccount.aspx):

```
Install-Package System.Security.AccessControl
Install-Package System.Security.Principal
```

after that usage is similar:

```
using System.Security.AccessControl;
using System.Security.Principal;

var fileSecurity = new FileSecurity(fileInfo.PhysicalPath, AccessControlSections.All);
// fileSecurity.GetOwner(typeof(NTAccount)) is available here
```

General rule right now is to google the full qualified name for a class and add `core` or `nuget` to it, so you'll definitely get needed file with it's new location.

Answer (score 2):

probably you can use File Info Provider into .net core..

```
IFileProvider provider = new PhysicalFileProvider(applicationRoot);
IDirectoryContents contents = provider.GetDirectoryContents(""); // the applicationRoot contents
IFileInfo fileInfo = provider.GetFileInfo("wwwroot/js/site.js"); // a file under applicationRoot
```

Iterate through `fileInfo` object.

See this for more information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/file-providers

Hope it helps.

Comment: It gives basic FileInfo, does not provide extended properties