# Adding a flag the file

Tags: c#, flags

I have two application client and server apps. My client application is checking xml then uploading it server. My server application is reading this xml. This is the senario.

I want to add a flag to xml in client side(Example ok,fail or 0,1 or true,false.)then upload it the server. Before reading it in server application, It will check the flag then read xml.

Note : My xml file size over 20 gb.

I tried to use Windows API Code Pack to add or edit File Properties but I couldn't.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you just on run-time, send the server the flag (e.g. OK, FAIL, etc.) and then send the XML, rather than add the flag to the XML?

Comment: I must add flag the xml file. Sending flag the server is not suitable for me.

Comment: Can you just create a tag like: `<flag>OK</flag>`? and then read just that tag, send it to the server, and if needed, send the rest of the XML file?

Comment: File size is over 20 gb so I want to resolve this problem without editing xml file text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have full access to the file system and it is NTFS, you can probably use an [alternate stream](http://blog.codefluententities.com/2013/03/14/manipulating-ntfs-alternate-data-streams-in-c-with-the-codefluent-runtime-client/) related to the file, but apart from the data.

For example you can write an Alternate Stream called *flag* with the *TRUE* value on command prompt by doing:

```
echo TRUE > C:\Path\file.xml:flag
```

Then, you can read the stream:

```
more < C:\Path\file.xml:flag
```

This will not change the file content.

There is no native .NET support for read/write NTFS alternate streams. But you can use WinApi p/invoke to access those streams: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/604970/122195

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For reading and writing large xml files you should using SAX method instead of DOM.  In C# there is an xmlreader class that use SAX method to read and wite your flag.