# C#, can I save a file from a stream or other to my single exe?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, file, stream, export

I would like to take a serialized file and save it to my recourses folder in project.

My reason for doing this (maybe there's a better way) is I have a published exe (single executable file) for the program that runs and when it creates a serialized file I don't want it to save it to desktop. I need to somehow save it to my exe without going outside of it.

Any advice on how I could do this?

Comment: The recommended place to save "data" for an application is a AppData location: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/app-settings/store-and-retrieve-app-data .... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.localuserappdatapath?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: If you want the settings/data to roam with the user when the login elsewhere then: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.userappdatapath?view=windowsdesktop-6.0 ... or...if its data all users share....https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.application.commonappdatapath?view=windowsdesktop-6.0

Comment: Save it to one of the _App Data_ folders. If you want it to be nearly undiscoverable, save it to _Isolated Storage_

Comment: @CSmith thanks that's a good suggestion

Comment: @Flydog57 also great, thanks; I haven't heard of the isolated storage folder. I may have to look into that. ig I could also just create a hidden directory in the appdata folder. I just hope I don't need admin rights to right to appdata folder.

Answer (score 0):

It's very ugly.....but you could use an "alternative data stream" on NTFS system.

http://ntfs.com/ntfs-multiple.htm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/streams

[How to read and modify NTFS Alternate Data Streams using .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/604960/how-to-read-and-modify-ntfs-alternate-data-streams-using-net)

https://blogs.msmvps.com/bsonnino/2016/11/24/alternate-data-streams-in-c/

https://oddvar.moe/2018/04/11/putting-data-in-alternate-data-streams-and-how-to-execute-it-part-2/

https://blog.foldersecurityviewer.com/ntfs-alternate-data-streams-the-good-and-the-bad/

https://www.irongeek.com/i.php?page=security/altds

You'll probably have security scanners stopping you from doing it.

In addition if you copy the from an NTFS volume to say FAT, then alternative data streams are lost.

Also some backup software may not backup ADS properly.

https://wiki.sep.de/wiki/index.php/Support_for_NTFS_alternate_data_streams_(ADS)_for_Windows

https://www.2brightsparks.com/resources/articles/ntfs-alternate-data-stream-ads.html

https://community.osr.com/discussion/89308/alternate-data-streams-and-backups

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Azure/en-US/007d5442-1cd8-4293-b717-b8fa72606189/ntfs-data-streams-broken-by-design-on-file-copy?forum=winserverfiles

Comment: thanks, but if there is not a simple way of doing it I am probably just storing them on the computer